# Maven, filtering NON-resource file

Tags: maven-2

I share a config file between several modules and I don't want the config file to be baked into any of the JARs.

How can i make Maven do (resource) filtering on the file which is not specified as a resource but is in a config folder on the same level as the root POM?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) and its [`resources:copy-resources`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) mojo. From the Examples:

> #### [Copy Resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)
>
> You can use the mojo copy-resources to
>   copy resources which are not in the
>   default maven layout or not declared
>   in the build/resources element and
>   attach it to a phase
>
> ```
> <project>
>   ...
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.3</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <id>copy-resources</id>
>             <!-- here the phase you need -->
>             <phase>validate</phase>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>copy-resources</goal>
>             </goals>
>             <configuration>
>               <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extra-resources</outputDirectory>
>               <resources>          
>                 <resource>
>                   <directory>src/non-packaged-resources</directory>
>                   <filtering>true</filtering>
>                 </resource>
>               </resources>              
>             </configuration>            
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>     ...
>   </build>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```

Another option would be to use the [Maven AntRun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and Ant filtering capabilities (e.g. with the [Filter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/filter.html) and/or the [Copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) tasks) but the above looks just fine.

Comment: Is this different than the `<build><resources>`... section?